# DateTime.ParseExact for : Fri Dec 7 16:36:21 2012

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I have the following string which I want to bind to `DateTime` object for further processing:

```
Fri Dec   7 16:36:21 2012
```

I tried this:

```
string format = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy";
DateTime.ParseExact(_srdfLag.CaptureTime, format,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

However, it throws an exception: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 24 hour date change format accordingly, you need `HH` `instead` of `hh`, also use`d` `instead` of `dd`.

```
string date = "Fri Dec 7 16:36:21 2012";
string format = "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Comment: Just tried with that :ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Giving same exception. There are 3 white spaces between Dec and 7. Removing those also giving same exception.

Comment: Anyways just tried with this : ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy and it worked.